# Как приложение может узнать кто его запустил?

Tags: c#

Приложение может запустить как пользователь так и другая программа, мне нужно отличать исполнителя.
Как приложение может узнать кто его запустил?

Comment: Если то приложение, которое выполнило запуск целевого, ещё не выгружено, и если прав хватит, и если нет пускача-прослойки, и ещё сотня всяких "если", то можно посмотреть папашку по дереву процессов.

Comment: К сожалению пускач будет выгружен

Comment: А тогда всё, цепляться не за что... впрочем, если под запуском "от пользователя" имеется в виду нечто типа запуска с ярлыка - так там папашкой будет Explorer текущего пользовательского сеанса, тогда как при запуске из кода приложения с последующим завершением программы-стартера папашкой будет корень древа процессов.

Comment: предлагаю просто сделать дом параметр запуска программы который это будет отслеживать. Если программа запускается с даным параметром - делаем соответствующие выводы. Остальными случаями вряд ли это возможно т.к. для компьютера нету разницы на самом деле кто именно реально запускает программу.